# Multi monitor remote desktop to Ubuntu

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

Is there some way or remote desktop solution (paid OR free) that I can use to remote from one Linux PC to another with multi-monitor support?

In other words, Computer A and Computer B both run Ubuntu.
Computer A has only one monitor.
Computer B has two monitors.

I remote into Computer A from Computer B. I would like to use both monitors on Computer B.

Is this possible?

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

**First Solution:**

[x2go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/start) is an Open Source remote desktop application for GNU/Linux that uses NX technology protocol.

**Install X2Go Server**

On Ubuntu 14.04:

Run the following commands to add X2Go repository and install it in Ubuntu 14.04 or higher versions.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession
```

On Ubuntu 12.04:

For Ubuntu 12.04 and previous versions, you can add X2Go repository and install it as shown below.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession
```

**Install X2Go Client**

X2Go Client is available for Windows, Mac OS X, and many Linux distributions.

Add X2Go repository as shown above in the X2Go server installation section depending upon the distribution you use.

```
Then, install X2Go client using command:
```

On Debian and Ubuntu like systems:

```
sudo apt-get install x2goclient
```

X2Go supports multimonitor. Open x2go client in the `New Session` window go to the `Input/output` tab.

In the `Display` section you can choose the radio button of `Use Whole Display` and choose number of displays you want to use (number range from 1 to the your number of monitors).

[image]

---

**Second Solution**

[FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) will probably do what you want.

It's better to compile [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) from sources because Multi-Monitor support is only available in versions >= 1.1.

Visit this [page](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation) to learn how to install it from source.

Now you can use xfreerdp command from terminal:

```
xfreerdp /multimon /u:username /v:server_address:server_port
```

where `username` is your username on server, `server_address` is server location (IP address or hostname) and `server_port` is port (leave empty without ":" for default port).

If you dont like to build from source you can still install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install freerdp-x11
```

But you have to be sure that the version is >1.1

Comment: Let me try this out when I can :)

Comment: Feel Free to do it... I already tested it ...

Comment: Using this option in x2goclient doesn't seem to behave as you describe. The "Display" option with "use whole display" only seems to select which display you want to use.

Comment: I tested my self as in the pic above. you can specify the number of displays you want to use

Comment: ...and I tested it both from Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1. I invite you to do some kind of screen capture like jing ( https://www.techsmith.com/jing.html ) and show that it can be done. If you can do that, I'll award the bounty. Otherwise it's hard for me to believe that you got this working since it doesn't work on my machine. :(

Comment: I'm not answering to get a bounty. but i'm telling you i tried myself and it works. I don't know why it doesn't in your machine, but for me it works

Comment: ok, well, thank you for your efforts thus far.

Comment: This only allows for a single monitor to be used, checking or unchecking "Xinerama extension" has no effect.

Comment: I'm with aikeru - this setting is for WHICH display, not how many displays. And the Xinerama option also does nothing for me.

Comment: I did this with freerdp :)

/usr/bin/xfreerdp /v:server.ip /u:user /p:password /multimon /rfx

Turn that command into a script and boom!

Answer (score 2):

I used [NoMachine NX](https://www.nomachine.com/) for a long time which worked well for me. The server run on a Ubuntu Server and I was able to connect from both Windows and Linux.
According to [this article](https://www.nomachine.com/AR09C00288), the previous version 3.5 (current is 4.x) already supported multiple monitors what is said to be improved in 4.x.

If this is what you are looking for, you could give it a try as there is a free version. When I used it the last time there were some limitations in the free version like only one session at a time. I can't tell you if it is still like that.

**Edit:** To what you said about:

> ...regardless of how many monitors are connected to the server (perhaps
>   zero!).

My Server was headless so you don't need to worry about it's monitors. It's not like VNC but opens an own session.

And in addition: There is also a completely [free version of NX](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX). But I haven't any experiences with it.

Comment: Let me try this out when I can :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a **simple solution** that works for me as I work remotely with multiple monitors as well as across platforms.(Windows, Mac, and Linux)

I use a program called Teamviewer, that can be located at [Teamviewer.com](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx) I am currently running it through wine but have run the linux version successfully as well. 
It will allow you to quickly switch between monitors although I haven't been successful at showing more than one at a time.

This has the *added perk of your being able to go to any computer*, sign in at their site, and access your computers from anywhere without loading the program.

Comment: Yeah. Switching between monitors wouldn't work for my use case. :( thanks tho. The server might actually be headless.

Answer (score 1):

- You can achieve that easily with x2go.
- On the **input/output** tab make sure to check the two options: **Fullscreen** ,**Xinerama**.

Example : [x2go setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owcUs.png)

[Read more here](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:usage:multi-display)